# Syntax problem with Bison and Flex during compilation and execution

Tags: flexbox, syntax-error, bison, yacc, lex

I'm currently working on a project that consists in parsing the content of a text file representing a plane ticket using `bison` and `flex`. I have created two files, ticket.y and ticket.l, to define grammar rules and corresponding regular expressions.

The example file I want to analyze is the following (`ExampleAirplaneTicket.txt`):

```
DOSSIER YBNUKR 
ANTOINE/DESAINT-EXUPERY
22/01/16 OS412  CDG 10:00  VIE 12:00    2:00
22/01/16 OS051  VIE 13:20  NRT +07:25   11:05 
23/01/16 OS8577 NRT 10:00  CHI 09:00    01:45
```

Here is the content of my `billet.l` (`ticket.l`) file:

```c
%{
#include "billet.tab.h"
void yyerror(const char *s);
%}

DIGIT [0-9]
ALPHA [A-Za-z]
SEP [ \t]

%%

"DOSSIER"               { return DOSSIER; }
{ALPHA}{6}              { return CODE_DOSSIER; }
{ALPHA}{3}"/"           { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return CODE_AEROPORT; }
{ALPHA}{4}+("/"{ALPHA}+)?("-"{ALPHA}+)?  { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return NOM_PRENOM; }
{DIGIT}{2}"/"{DIGIT}{2}"/"{DIGIT}{2} { return DATE; }
{ALPHA}{2}{DIGIT}{2,4}  { return NUM_VOL; }
{ALPHA}{3}              { return CODE_AEROPORT; }
{DIGIT}{2}":"{DIGIT}{2} { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return HEURE_OR_DUREE_VOL; }
"+"                     { return PLUS; }
{SEP}+                  { }
\n                      { return NEWLINE; }
.                       { fprintf(stderr, "Caractère non autorisé: '%s'\n", yytext); exit(1); }

%%
```

And here is the content of my `billet.y` (`ticket.y`) file:

```c
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void yyerror(const char *s);
int yylex();
%}

%union {
  char *sval;
}

%token DOSSIER CODE_DOSSIER NEWLINE PLUS
%token <sval> DATE NUM_VOL CODE_AEROPORT HEURE_OR_DUREE_VOL
%token <sval> NOM_PRENOM

%type <sval> nom_prenom
%type <sval> heure_arrivee
%type <sval> heure_avec_plus

%%

billet: DOSSIER CODE_DOSSIER NEWLINE infos_passager NEWLINE vols;

infos_passager: nom_prenom '/' nom_prenom NEWLINE { printf("Infos passager : %s / %s\n", $1, $3); };

vols: vol NEWLINE vols | vol NEWLINE;

vol: DATE NUM_VOL CODE_AEROPORT HEURE_OR_DUREE_VOL CODE_AEROPORT heure_arrivee HEURE_OR_DUREE_VOL { printf("Vol : %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7); };

heure_arrivee: heure_avec_plus | HEURE_OR_DUREE_VOL;

heure_avec_plus: PLUS HEURE_OR_DUREE_VOL { $$ = $2; };

nom_prenom: NOM_PRENOM;

%%

int main() {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur de syntaxe : %s\n", s);
}
```

When I compile everything, I can't test my program on the `ExampleAirplaneTicket.txt` file.
I simply have a syntax error, and despite several attempts, I have not been able to solve these problems or even figure out where it comes from.

I am looking for help to understand and solve these problems. If you have any suggestions or advice on how to solve these errors, I would be very grateful.

I tried to implement a parser using `flex` and `bison` to parse a specific text format representing airline ticket information. I wrote the .l and .y files and made the necessary adjustments based on the previous problems. Now I expect the program to compile successfully and parse the file ExampleAirlineTicket.txt without any syntax errors or other problems. Except that when I test with the file I just get a syntax error, but no idea where it comes from.

When I compile `billet.l` I get this warning (I don't think it's a problem):

```
billet.l:17: warning, the rule can't match
billet.l:20: warning, the rule can't match
```

No warning when I compile `billet.y`, and when I compile everything with `gcc` either.

But when I test with the text file I get this :

```
Syntax error
```

UPDATE :

I combined the tokens HEURE and DUREE_VOL into one token : TIME_OR_FLIGHT_TIME .
My files above have been updated.

I don't have warnings on line 17 and 20 anymore but I have a warning on line 18 when compiling billet.l.

And still the same syntax error when executing the text file

File billet.l :

```
I modified line 15 to change the pattern from {ALPHA}+("/"{ALPHA}+)?("-"{ALPHA}+)? to {ALPHA}{4}+("/"{ALPHA}+)?("-"{ALPHA}+)? in order to assume the name has at least 4 letters.
I also changed the token returned on line 15 from NOM_PRENOM to STRING.
```

file billet.y :

```
I added a new token <sval> STRING to the list of tokens.
I modified the nom_prenom rule to accept either STRING or STRING / STRING.
```

I have new errors to compile from billet.y (and no billet.l anymore) :

```
ticket.y: warning: 1 conflict per offset/reduction [-Wconflicts-sr]
ticket.y: note: run with "-Wcounterexamples" option to generate counterexamples of conflicts
```

And still a syntax error when I execute my text file ExampleAirplaneTicket.txt

Comment: Your post should include the errors you get when you compile your program and/or when you run it.

Comment: @RachidK. I just added it at the end of the message

Comment: It may help to add `%define parse.error verbose` to your bison file. It will give you a better error message.

Comment: In line 18, you have the same pb as mentioned in my answer: the pattern of line 15 (NOM_PRENOM) covers the pattern of line 18 (CODE_AEROPORT). So, I that case, you should modify you grammar adding a rule to describe the string with the NOM and PRENOM: USE a simple STRING pattern and make a rule which describe the nom_prenom which is either STRING or STRING "/" STRING...

Comment: As a 1st try, before modifying your grammar, modify temporarily line 15 as:
{ALPHA}{4}+(....  to suppose that the name is at least 4 alphas in order to make the rule in line 18  more specific (3 alphas only)

Comment: @RachidK. Thank you ! 
I edited as you requested, updated the post and explained what I had done, as well as the other errors that appeared (I don't think they are disturbing, but I still have the syntax error)

Comment: You mix the two proposition. STRING token is to be introduced if you modify the grammar. In a first step, just keep your grammar as it is but modifying only rule at ine 15.

Comment: @RachidK.
Forgive me, I did everything, I have updated the post , so I have no warning anywhere but still the syntax error at execution

Comment: @Elblocktri: I updated my answer with a draft solution. Your pb come from the lexical analyzer which does not discriminate all the patterns (you try to make too much analysis in it, let the grammar do the work). The proposed answer must be refined...

Comment: It works! Thank you again very much, I understood where the problem was

Comment: BTW, Bison supports Posix character classes. For example your `{DIGIT}` is an equivalent of `[[:digit:]]`, `{ALPHA}` is `[[:alpha:]]` and `{SEP}` is `[[:blank:]]`. You can find more here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following warnings from flex:

```
billet.l:17: warning, the rule can't match
billet.l:20: warning, the rule can't match
```

come from the fact that the rule of:

- `NOM_PRENOM` covers what is expected by the rule of `CODE_AEROPORT`
- `HEURE` token is the same pattern as the rule of `DUREE_VOL`

So, some of the tokens (`CODE_AEROPORT` and `DUREE_VOL`) will never appear. This may be the reason why you get the default "Syntax error" message.

**Note**: The C source file generated by bison shows that "Syntax error" is reported when the number of reported tokens (yycount internal variable) is 0:

```
/*
[...]
     - The only way there can be no lookahead present (in yychar) is if
       this state is a consistent state with a default action.  Thus,
       detecting the absence of a lookahead is sufficient to determine
       that there is no unexpected or expected token to report.  In that
       case, just report a simple "syntax error".
[...]
*/
[...]
  switch (yycount)
    {
# define YYCASE_(N, S)                      \
      case N:                               \
        yyformat = S;                       \
      break
      YYCASE_(0, YY_("syntax error"));
      YYCASE_(1, YY_("syntax error, unexpected %s"));
      YYCASE_(2, YY_("syntax error, unexpected %s, expecting %s"));
      YYCASE_(3, YY_("syntax error, unexpected %s, expecting %s or %s"));
      YYCASE_(4, YY_("syntax error, unexpected %s, expecting %s or %s or %s"));
      YYCASE_(5, YY_("syntax error, unexpected %s, expecting %s or %s or %s or %s"));
# undef YYCASE_
    }
```

### Update

Update from the latest modifications of the post. There are ambiguities in your lexical analyzer. The work to discriminate the inputs should be done in the grammar. Here is a proposition where the number of tokens in the lexical analyzer is reduced and where the rules in the grammar are more detailed.

Here is the simplified lexical analyzer (billet.l):

```
%{
#include "billet.tab.h"
void yyerror(const char *s);
%}

DIGIT [0-9]
ALPHA [A-Za-z]
ALPHA2 [-A-Za-z]
SEP [ \t]

%%

"DOSSIER"               { return DOSSIER; }
{ALPHA2}+               { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return STRING; }
{DIGIT}+                { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return NUM; }
{ALPHA}{2}{DIGIT}{2,4}  { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return NUM_VOL; }
"+"                     { return PLUS; }
{SEP}+                  { }
\n                      { return NEWLINE; }
"/"                     { return SLASH; }
":"                     { return COLON; }
.                       { fprintf(stderr, "Caractère non autorisé: '%s'\n", yytext); exit(1); }

%%
```

And a little more elaborated syntaxic analyzer (billet.y):

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void yyerror(const char *s);
int yylex();
%}

%union {
  char *sval;
}

%token DOSSIER CODE_DOSSIER NEWLINE PLUS SLASH COLON
%token <sval> DATE NUM_VOL STRING NUM
%token <sval> NOM_PRENOM

%type <sval> duree_vol
%type <sval> heure
%type <sval> airport
%type <sval> nom_prenom
%type <sval> date
%type <sval> heure_arrivee
%type <sval> heure_avec_plus
%define parse.error verbose
%%

liste : billet liste | billet

billet: DOSSIER STRING NEWLINE infos_passager NEWLINE vols;

infos_passager: nom_prenom { printf("Infos passager : %s\n", $1); free($1); };

vols: vol NEWLINE vols | vol NEWLINE;

vol: date NUM_VOL airport heure airport heure_arrivee duree_vol { printf("Vol : %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7); free($1); free($2); free($3); free($4); free($5); free($6); free($7); };

duree_vol : heure 

heure : NUM COLON NUM { char str[20]; snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%s:%s", $1, $3); $$ = strdup(str); free($1); free($3); }

airport : STRING

date: NUM SLASH NUM SLASH NUM { char str[20]; snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%s/%s/%s", $1, $3, $5); $$ = strdup(str); free($1); free($3); free($5); }

heure_arrivee: heure_avec_plus | heure;

heure_avec_plus: PLUS heure { $$ = $2; };

nom_prenom: STRING | STRING SLASH STRING { char str[120]; snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%s/%s", $1, $3); $$ = strdup(str); free($1); free($3); };

%%

int main() {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur de syntaxe : %s\n", s);
}
```

Built it:

```
$ flex billet.l
$ bison -d billet.y
$ gcc billet.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl
```

And run it with something like:

```
$ ./a.out < input.txt
Infos passager : ANTOINE/DESAINT-EXUPERY
Vol : 22/01/16 OS412 CDG 10:00 VIE 12:00 2:00
Vol : 22/01/16 OS051 VIE 13:20 NRT 07:25 11:05
Vol : 23/01/16 OS8577 NRT 10:00 CHI 09:00 01:45
```

Comment: I modified what I could, I have a new warning line 18, I still do not understand where it comes from... And I still have the syntax error at runtime

Comment: If for some reasons you can't discriminate two tokens with a pattern, use the same token for both. This is the syntax analyzer which will be able to determine if the token is expected or not in the input stream. Example, use HEURE_OR_DUREE_VOL for the same pattern instead of two separate HEURE and DUREE_VOL as they have the same pattern. And then, this will be used in the grammar.

Comment: I modified as you suggested, I still have the same warning at line 18 and the syntax error at execution...

Comment: You should update your post with some "update" topic to show what you are doing...

Comment: I modified the files in the main post!